# Рисование направляющих в Google Maps API Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, android-canvas

В данном API есть функции рисования полигона и ломаных линий. После рисования полигона нужно произвести разметку прямыми линиями как это показано на рисунке ниже. Есть ли какие нибудь стандартные способы реализации данной функции? Если нет, то с помощью каких инструментов можно реализовать такое? Пишу на Java для Android.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]